# Shell script - Sorting text file by column that will & will not exist

Tags: shell, sorting, unix

I want to sort a text file according to the 4th column (eg, 16 or 18 or 5 or 7) in the file, but as you can see, there are some lines that do not have that field (eg : ) and after sorting they should be below the line they were originally below.

Example data

```
INSERT,SLT_TEST_5,1218738496,16,DEBUG3,,DEBUG_LEVEL1
<v s=""MONTHLY_PEAK_DWNLOAD""/>
</a><a n=""thresholdScheme"">
<o t=""PM_UsageMonitorConfigThreshold""> 
INSERT,SLT_TEST_1,1218738496,18,DEBUG3,,DEBUG_LEVEL4
<v s=""ORANGE""/>
INSERT,SLT_TEST_3,5555738111,5,DEBUG3,,DEBUG_LEVEL1
INSERT,SLT_TEST_1,9998738342,7,DEBUG3,,DEBUG_LEVEL2
```

Example output (desired)

```
INSERT,SLT_TEST_3,5555738111,5,DEBUG3,,DEBUG_LEVEL1
INSERT,SLT_TEST_1,9998738342,7,DEBUG3,,DEBUG_LEVEL2
INSERT,SLT_TEST_5,1218738496,16,DEBUG3,,DEBUG_LEVEL1
<v s=""MONTHLY_PEAK_DWNLOAD""/>
</a><a n=""thresholdScheme"">
<o t=""PM_UsageMonitorConfigThreshold""> 
INSERT,SLT_TEST_1,1218738496,18,DEBUG3,,DEBUG_LEVEL4
<v s=""ORANGE""/>
```

Comment: Is `\nINSERT` a safe and reliable indicator of the beginning of the lines/entries that you want to sort on?

Comment: Not really. From the data above, the 4th ~ 6th & 8th line doesn't start with INSERT.

Comment: Yes, but those are the lines that you *don't* want to sort on. You want those "bundled" with their preceding lines. Does every to-sort line start with `INSERT`?

Comment: Yes. It starts with INSERT for all the entries.

Comment: Does every line you want 'bundled with' the previous line start with '<'?

Comment: Nope, it does not have a fix pattern for the "bundled with" lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there won't be embedded commas before the sort field, you could use `awk` to help with the sort and remove any extraneous information afterward:

```
awk -F',' -vi=0 '
/^INSERT/ { i=$4 }
{ printf("%08d%08d\t%s\n", i, NR, $0) }
' < data | sort | sed -e 's/^[^\t]*\t//' > newdata
```

That just feeds an input file "data" to `awk`, which will insert a formatted copy of the 4th field before the data itself in the form `XXXXXXXX.NNNNNNNN`, where `XXXXXXXX` represents an 8-digit representation of the value in the fourth field of the last `INSERT ...` line found, and `NNNNNNNN` represents the record number (line number) formatted as an 8-digit value. The original data and the formatted data is separated by a tab character. A special case in which the file doesn't start with `INSERT` (e.g. a blank line, a comment explaining the contents of the file, etc.) is treated as if the last `INSERT` line had a fourth field with a value of 0. Here's a clipped sample of the resulting output with some additional lines inserted for testing:

```
0000000000000001    # This file contains data.
0000001600000002    INSERT,SLT_TEST_5,1218738496,16,DEBUG3,,DEBUG_LEVEL1
0000001600000003    <v s=""MONTHLY_PEAK_DWNLOAD""/>
0000001600000004    </a><a n=""thresholdScheme"">
0000001600000005    <o t=""PM_UsageMonitorConfigThreshold""> 
0000001800000006    INSERT,SLT_TEST_1,1218738496,18,DEBUG3,,DEBUG_LEVEL4
0000001800000007    <v s=""ORANGE""/>
0000000500000008    INSERT,SLT_TEST_3,5555738111,5,DEBUG3,,DEBUG_LEVEL1
0000000700000009    INSERT,SLT_TEST_1,9998738342,7,DEBUG3,,DEBUG_LEVEL2
0000000700000010    I'm a little teapot.
```

The resulting lines are passed to `sort`, which will sort the lines it receives. `sed` will then strip the lines that the `sort` utility outputs of the information the `awk` script originally created, resulting in a sort based on the fourth field without altering the order of the lines that don't begin with `INSERT`, which is output to a file "newdata":

```
# This file contains data.
INSERT,SLT_TEST_3,5555738111,5,DEBUG3,,DEBUG_LEVEL1
INSERT,SLT_TEST_1,9998738342,7,DEBUG3,,DEBUG_LEVEL2
I'm a little teapot.
INSERT,SLT_TEST_5,1218738496,16,DEBUG3,,DEBUG_LEVEL1
<v s=""MONTHLY_PEAK_DWNLOAD""/>
</a><a n=""thresholdScheme"">
<o t=""PM_UsageMonitorConfigThreshold""> 
INSERT,SLT_TEST_1,1218738496,18,DEBUG3,,DEBUG_LEVEL4
<v s=""ORANGE""/>
```

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks a bunch! I was going for similar approach initially,  but I missed something. What I missed was, instead of making them having the same value, I added a sub index for them (eg: 3.1, 3.2) and that ruined the sort and I abandon the idea. I was stupid for not able to figure it out. Thanks again <3

Comment: @Xeon I had approximately the same idea initially, so it's not stupid at all. Sometimes you just need a fresh pair of eyes to look at the problem and find a solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit fried at this point and am having trouble understanding what part of this I'm not getting exactly right but something like this seems to work on your test data (with the exception of adding a "blank" record/entry to the top.

```
awk -v RS='\n?INSERT' -F , '{
    gsub(/\n$/,"");
    m[sprintf("%04d",$4)]=substr(RS,3)$0
}
END {
    l = asorti(m, mm);
    for (i = 1; i <= l; i++) {
        print m[mm[i]]
    }
}'
```

Whereas this version double inserts `RS` on the first record (and I can't see why at the moment either).

```
awk -v RS='\nINSERT' -F , '{
    gsub(/\n$/,"");
    m[sprintf("%04d",$4)]=substr(RS,2)$0
}
END {
    l = asorti(m, mm);
    for (i = 1; i <= l; i++) {
        print m[mm[i]]
    }
}'
```

The `sprintf` is so that `asorti` sorts the fields correctly (string sorting). That needs to be big enough to pad every field to the same width.

Comment: I am getting an error, 
awk: cmd. line:6: Call to undefined function

I am running on
CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW KL-002404 2.0.4(0.287/5/3) 2015-08-03 00:00 i686 GNU/Linux


Sorry, I am totally new to Linux

Comment: @Xeon `asorti` is a GNU awk function. Do you happen to have a `gawk` command available? If not, installing `gawk` should fix things.

Comment: @Xeon Then try using `gawk` in the command above instead of `awk`.

Comment: Wait, I think I don't have it. I'm kinda confused here. I am using mobaxterm, it has awk and not gawk I think.

Comment: Based on what I've seen on the [MobaXterm features](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/features.html) page, there is a package manager (MobApt) that you can use to install `gawk` if you don't have it.